# How to remove/delete a row in javascript array by having value of first item of array row?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I create array like this:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push({ url: urlValue, filename: fileNameValue });
```

urlValue and fileNamevalue are javascript variables.
After a while my array will get lots of items and if i want to delete a row by having urlValue how i can delete that row?(by row i mean delete that urlValue and fileNameValue).For Example i want delete a row that has urlValue= http://www.somsite.com/pics/picture12.jpg and fileNameValue=picseasonNewName.jpg

Comment: You want to delete an entry in the array containing the object that has a certain `url:urlValue` then?

Comment: Thanks for reply . I want delete url:urlValue and its corresponding filenameLfileNameValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the entire object from the array using

```
function removeRow(value){ 
    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        if(myArray[i].urlValue == value)
           myArray.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery, you can use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
var result = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.url !== "urlValue"; });
```

This will return an array of objects whose url is **not** the target value, effectively deleting your array entry.

Demo: [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/fiveco/watch?js,console)

Comment: i tried your code inside function and passed it a variable called a:var result = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.url !== a; }); and still that item exist !

Comment: Can you show more of your actual code? The demo above works flawlessly, so I'd like to see more of what your variables look like.

Comment: function removeRow(a) {

alert("imageURL:"+a);
var result = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.url !==a; });

console.log( result );
}

Comment: You probably didn't update myArray. Your function works fine. See the demo where myArray is updated in your function. Happily works as expected. http://jsbin.com/junelo/watch?js,console

Answer (score 2):

[Updating an array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp)

1. Loop an array.
2. Compare if the item's link is equal to the item you want to delete.
3. You update the array eliminating what was found

**Demo:**

```js
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push({ url: "http://www.somsite.com/pics/picture10.jpg", filename: "" });
myArray.push({ url: "http://www.somsite.com/pics/picture12.jpg", filename: "" });
myArray.push({ url: "http://www.somsite.com/pics/picture14.jpg", filename: "" });

var i = 0, urlToFind = "http://www.somsite.com/pics/picture12.jpg";

//Remove/Delete array item

while(i < myArray.length){
   myArray[i++].url == urlToFind ? myArray.splice(i-1, 1) : 0
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(myArray))
```

Answer (score 1):

The terms you are using in your question are not the right ones for javascript.

What Drakes wrote in the comments expresses better what you want

> delete an entry in the array containing the object that has a certain
>   url:urlValue

Javascript has some [built-in functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for working with arrays.

You could use filter to make a new array without the entry you wish to remove, and it is also useful if the urlValue is not unique.

```
function removeEntries(arr, value) {
  return arr.filter(function (entry) {
    return entry.url !== value;
  })
}
```